# Is there any way to allow access to only the requests coming from the same domain by configuring in wildfly

Tags: openshift, wildfly-10

I looked at this question but this is about restricting by an IP. My application is hosted on Openshift. I looked at statica, but it costs a lot.

[Is there any way to restrict access by configuring in WildFly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719044/is-there-any-way-to-restrict-access-by-configuring-in-wildfly/36486984#36486984)

Please let me know, if there is a way to configure wildfly to allow access to only requests coming from a given domain.

For example, admin.example.com should allow requests coming only from www.example.com

Thank you,